# How do I properly instantiate an arraylist that can hold both the player and the dealer?

Tags: java, blackjack

I am making a multiplayer Blackjack game in Java for my APCS Class. I need to be able to store both the player and dealer in an arraylist. What is the proper way to instantiate an arraylist. Here is the class where the problem resides.

```
package BlackJack;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import static java.lang.Character.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import BlackJack.Card;
import BlackJack.BlackJackCard;
import BlackJack.Deck;
import BlackJack.AbstractPlayer;
import BlackJack.Player;
import BlackJack.Dealer;

public class TheMultiPlayerGame extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    ArrayList<Object> Ai = new ArrayList<Object>(4);
    private Dealer dealer = new Dealer();
    private Player[] playa = new Player[3];

    private Player player;
    private boolean start;
    private boolean hit;
    private boolean finish;
    private boolean show;
    private Font font;
    int playerTotal = 0;
    int dealerTotal = 0;
    int playerWinTotal = 0;
    int dealerWinTotal = 0;
    String j = "";
    String p = "";

    public TheMultiPlayerGame() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        font = new Font("TAHOMA", Font.BOLD, 12);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        dealer = new Dealer();
        Ai.set(1, playa[0]);
        Ai.set(2, playa[1]);
        Ai.set(3, playa[2]);
        Ai.set(0, dealer);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics window) {
        super.paintComponent(window);

        window.setColor(Color.blue);
        window.setFont(font);
        window.drawString("BlackJack GUI", 25, 50);
        window.drawString("PRESS B to start/restart the game.", 25, 100);
        window.drawString("PRESS H to hit - PLAYER", 325, 100);
        window.drawString("PRESS F to finish(DEALER hits).", 25, 130);
        window.drawString("PRESS X to see the results.", 325, 130);
        window.drawString(j, 10, 530);
        window.drawString(p, 10, 90);
        window.drawString("Player WinCount = " + playerWinTotal, 600, 100);
        window.drawString("Dealer WinCount = " + dealerWinTotal, 600, 130);
        window.drawString("Dealer Score = " + dealerTotal, 600, 200);
        window.drawString("Player Score = " + playerTotal, 600, 250);
        Ai.set(1, playa[0]);
        Ai.set(2, playa[1]);
        Ai.set(3, playa[2]);
        Ai.set(0, dealer);

        if (start == true) {
            //reset the dealer and player hands
            dealer = new Dealer();
            player = new Player();
            dealer.shuffle();
            Ai.set(0, dealer);
            System.out.println(Ai.get(0).numCardsLeftInDeck());

            //add two cards to dealer and player
            for (int x = 1; x < Ai.size(); x++) {
                Ai.get(x).addCardToHand(Ai.get(0).deal());

                Ai.get(x).addCardToHand(Ai.get(0).deal());
            }
            playerTotal = player.getHandValue();
            dealerTotal = dealer.getHandValue();
            repaint();
            start = false;
        }
        else if (hit == true) {
            if (playerTotal < 21) {
                player.addCardToHand(dealer.deal());
                playerTotal = player.getHandValue();
                repaint();
            }
            hit = false;
        }
        else if (finish == true) {
            dealer.addCardToHand(dealer.deal());
            dealerTotal = dealer.getHandValue();
            finish = false;
            show = true;
        }

        if (show == true) {
            //determine who won the game
            dealerTotal = dealer.getHandValue();
            playerTotal = player.getHandValue();
            if (playerTotal > 21 && dealerTotal <= 21) {
                j = "\nDealer wins - Player busted! " + playerTotal + " : " + dealerTotal;
                dealerWinTotal++;
            }
            else if (playerTotal <= 21 && dealerTotal > 21) {
                j = "\nPlayer wins - Dealer busted! " + playerTotal + " : " + dealerTotal;
                playerWinTotal++;
            }
            else if (playerTotal > 21 && dealerTotal > 21) {
                j = "Both players bust!";
            }
            else if (playerTotal < dealerTotal) {
                j = "\nDealer has bigger hand value! " + playerTotal + " : " + dealerTotal;
                dealerWinTotal++;
            }
            else {
                j = "\nPlayer has bigger hand value! " + playerTotal + " : " + dealerTotal;
                playerWinTotal++;
            }
            repaint();
            show = false;
        }

        window.drawString("DEALER ", 50, 190);
        dealer.drawHand(window, 0, 190);

        window.drawString("PLAYER ", 50, 365);
        player.drawHand(window, 0, 365);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'b' || e.getKeyChar() == 'B') {
            start = true;
            repaint();
        }
        else if (e.getKeyChar() == 'h' || e.getKeyChar() == 'H') {
            hit = true;
            repaint();
        }
        else if (e.getKeyChar() == 'f' || e.getKeyChar() == 'F') {
            finish = true;
            repaint();
        }
        else if (e.getKeyChar() == 'x' || e.getKeyChar() == 'X') {
            show = true;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Make a Player and Dealer share the same [*interface*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), say, `CardHolder`. Then use an `List<CardHolder>`. Now you have a list of Players and Dealers who support various actions relating to cards (such as `addCardToHand` and `getHandValue`).

Comment: Why don't you create superclass which will extend in Player and Dealer both and use that class as your object in Collection

Comment: @Anonymous827364 Both comments (either using an interface or a superclass) are better than creating an ArrayList of Objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your current initialization wouldn't work.

You can change it to :

```
 Ai.add(dealer);
 Ai.add(playa[0]);
 Ai.add(playa[1]);
 Ai.add(playa[2]);
```

However, if the Dealer and the Players don't implement a common interface or share a common super class (other than Object), I don't see the point in putting them in that ArrayList.

Comment: They share an abstract class known as AbstractPlayer.

Comment: @Anonymous827364 In that case, the type of `Ai` should be `List<AbstractPlayer>`, not `ArrayList<Object>`.